# Base Url getting append in external url in header

Tags: magento-1.9, url, base-url, external

I have a text field in System config, where url is put say wwww.facebook.com.
Now when I am echoing the value from config in header it's giving me correct value.
But when I am putting it in this code and printing it's giving  url as **www.mybaseurl.com/www.facebook.com**

Why is my baseurl getting append in front of that url? I am writing this code in header.phtml

**CODE:**

```
$facebook = Mage::getStoreConfig('social/socialgroup/facebook');
$twitter = Mage::getStoreConfig('social/socialgroup/twitter');
$google = Mage::getStoreConfig('social/socialgroup/google');
```

---

```
      <li><a href="<?php
      if ($twitter !== ""):echo $twitter;
       else: echo "javascript:void(0);";
       endif;
       ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
       <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php
        if ($facebook == ""):echo "javascript:void(0);";
          else: echo $facebook;
           endif;
          ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="<?php
          if ($google !== ""):echo $google;
          else: echo "javascript:void(0);";
           endif;
            ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: please post the initial code , can u put the code where $facebook is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set absolute url in href it should be start with http:// or https://.

Please verify your `$facebook` variable and prefix it with https:// if not present.

```
function addhttp($url, $is_secure = false) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = ($is_secure ? "https://" : "http://") . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```